# Is it possible to find an object in the array of which only those elements that are specified in the request? Elastic Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Lets imagine I have 3 objects with the next structure:

```
     {
        "name": "Test_1",
        "attributes":[
            {
                "name": "attribute_1"
            },
            {
                "name": "attribute_2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Test_2",
        "attributes":[
            {
                "name": "attribute_1"
            },
            {
                "name": "attribute_2"
            },
    {
                "name": "attribute_3"
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "name": "Test_3",
        "attributes":[
            {
                "name": "attribute_2"
            },
            {
                "name": "attribute_3"
            }
        ]
    }
```

that are stored in Elastic Search and I wanna find those objects that contain only these values attributes.name = attribute_1, attribute_2

So, as result, I wanna get the 1st object because this object contains ONLY those specified values, no more, no less

Answer (score 0):

I your field is Nested Type I believe this query should help you.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "attributes.name": "attribute_1"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "attributes.name": "attribute_2"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```